# Accessing a specific xml element where it is a duplicate using python and lxml

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

I have a xml file that looks like the following

```
  <_gmd_citation>
    <_gmd_CI_Citation>
      <_gmd_title xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
          <_gco_CharacterString>Conservation Areas</_gco_CharacterString>
        </_gmd_title>
      <_gmd_alternateTitle _gco_nilReason="missing" />
      <_gmd_date>
        <_gmd_CI_Date>
          <_gmd_date xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
              <_gco_Date>2018-07-24</_gco_Date>
            </_gmd_date>
          <_gmd_dateType>
            <_gmd_CI_DateTypeCode codeListValue="publication" codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/Codelist/gmxCodelists.xml#CI_DateTypeCode" />
          </_gmd_dateType>
        </_gmd_CI_Date>
      </_gmd_date>
      <_gmd_date>
        <_gmd_CI_Date>
          <_gmd_date xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
              <_gco_Date>2013-11-15</_gco_Date>
            </_gmd_date>
          <_gmd_dateType>
            <_gmd_CI_DateTypeCode codeListValue="creation" codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/Codelist/gmxCodelists.xml#CI_DateTypeCode" />
          </_gmd_dateType>
        </_gmd_CI_Date>
      </_gmd_date>
      <_gmd_date>
        <_gmd_CI_Date>
          <_gmd_date xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
              **<_gco_Date>2016-11-11</_gco_Date>**
            </_gmd_date>
          <_gmd_dateType>
            <_gmd_CI_DateTypeCode codeListValue="**revision**" codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/Codelist/gmxCodelists.xml#CI_DateTypeCode" />
          </_gmd_dateType>
        </_gmd_CI_Date>
      </_gmd_date>
      <_gmd_identifier>
        <_gmd_RS_Identifier>
          <_gmd_authority _gco_nilReason="missing" />
          <_gmd_code>
            <_gco_CharacterString>0000</_gco_CharacterString>
          </_gmd_code>
          <_gmd_codeSpace xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
              <_gco_CharacterString>abc</_gco_CharacterString>
            </_gmd_codeSpace>
        </_gmd_RS_Identifier>
      </_gmd_identifier>
    </_gmd_CI_Citation>
```

What i would like to do is to change the _gco_Date if the codeListValue is == 'revision'.

The issue I am having is that the element _gco_date appears multiple times.
I can iterate through the elements like so

```
for elem in treed.getiterator():
    print elem.tag
        if elem.tag == '_gmd_CI_DateTypeCode':
            if elem.attrib['codeListValue'] == 'revision':
                aa = elem.attrib['codeListValue']
                    print aa
```

but I cant seem to specify the tag I want to change.
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Sounds doable with [`xpath`](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html).

Comment: What do you mean "can't seem to"?

Comment: @mad-physicist . The tag that I want to change is _gco_Date, if the codeListValue = revision, but they are in 2 seperate tags.

Comment: So have you looked at xpath?

Comment: @MapMan can BeautifulSoup be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of iterating over elements and testing tag names and attribute values, try using [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/).

By using a [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#predicates) (`[ ]`) we can easily select exactly what we need without iteration.

Example...

** **Updated with namespaces based on discussion in comments.** **

**XML Input** (input.xml)

```xml
<gmd:citation xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco">
    <gmd:CI_Citation>
        <gmd:title xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
            <gco:CharacterString>Conservation Areas</gco:CharacterString>
        </gmd:title>
        <gmd:alternateTitle gco:nilReason="missing" />
        <gmd:date>
            <gmd:CI_Date>
                <gmd:date xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
                    <gco:Date>2018-07-24</gco:Date>
                </gmd:date>
                <gmd:dateType>
                    <gmd:CI_DateTypeCode codeListValue="publication" codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/Codelist/gmxCodelists.xml#CI_DateTypeCode" />
                </gmd:dateType>
            </gmd:CI_Date>
        </gmd:date>
        <gmd:date>
            <gmd:CI_Date>
                <gmd:date xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
                    <gco:Date>2013-11-15</gco:Date>
                </gmd:date>
                <gmd:dateType>
                    <gmd:CI_DateTypeCode codeListValue="creation" codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/Codelist/gmxCodelists.xml#CI_DateTypeCode" />
                </gmd:dateType>
            </gmd:CI_Date>
        </gmd:date>
        <gmd:date>
            <gmd:CI_Date>
                <gmd:date xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
                    <gco:Date>2016-11-11</gco:Date>
                </gmd:date>
                <gmd:dateType>
                    <gmd:CI_DateTypeCode codeListValue="revision" codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/Codelist/gmxCodelists.xml#CI_DateTypeCode" />
                </gmd:dateType>
            </gmd:CI_Date>
        </gmd:date>
        <gmd:identifier>
            <gmd:RS_Identifier>
                <gmd:authority gco:nilReason="missing" />
                <gmd:code>
                    <gco:CharacterString>0000</gco:CharacterString>
                </gmd:code>
                <gmd:codeSpace xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
                    <gco:CharacterString>abc</gco:CharacterString>
                </gmd:codeSpace>
            </gmd:RS_Identifier>
        </gmd:identifier>
    </gmd:CI_Citation>
</gmd:citation>
```

**Python**

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("input.xml")

ns = {"gmd": "http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd", "gco": "http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco"}

try:
    elem = tree.xpath("//gmd:CI_Date[gmd:dateType/gmd:CI_DateTypeCode/"
                      "@codeListValue='revision']/gmd:date/gco:Date", namespaces=ns)[0]
    elem.text = "NEW VALUE"
except IndexError:
    pass

print etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True)
```

**Output**

```xml
<gmd:citation xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco">
    <gmd:CI_Citation>
        <gmd:title xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
            <gco:CharacterString>Conservation Areas</gco:CharacterString>
        </gmd:title>
        <gmd:alternateTitle gco:nilReason="missing"/>
        <gmd:date>
            <gmd:CI_Date>
                <gmd:date xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
                    <gco:Date>2018-07-24</gco:Date>
                </gmd:date>
                <gmd:dateType>
                    <gmd:CI_DateTypeCode codeListValue="publication" codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/Codelist/gmxCodelists.xml#CI_DateTypeCode"/>
                </gmd:dateType>
            </gmd:CI_Date>
        </gmd:date>
        <gmd:date>
            <gmd:CI_Date>
                <gmd:date xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
                    <gco:Date>2013-11-15</gco:Date>
                </gmd:date>
                <gmd:dateType>
                    <gmd:CI_DateTypeCode codeListValue="creation" codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/Codelist/gmxCodelists.xml#CI_DateTypeCode"/>
                </gmd:dateType>
            </gmd:CI_Date>
        </gmd:date>
        <gmd:date>
            <gmd:CI_Date>
                <gmd:date xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
                    <gco:Date>NEW VALUE</gco:Date>
                </gmd:date>
                <gmd:dateType>
                    <gmd:CI_DateTypeCode codeListValue="revision" codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/Codelist/gmxCodelists.xml#CI_DateTypeCode"/>
                </gmd:dateType>
            </gmd:CI_Date>
        </gmd:date>
        <gmd:identifier>
            <gmd:RS_Identifier>
                <gmd:authority gco:nilReason="missing"/>
                <gmd:code>
                    <gco:CharacterString>0000</gco:CharacterString>
                </gmd:code>
                <gmd:codeSpace xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
                    <gco:CharacterString>abc</gco:CharacterString>
                </gmd:codeSpace>
            </gmd:RS_Identifier>
        </gmd:identifier>
    </gmd:CI_Citation>
</gmd:citation>
```

**Important:** Make sure the two namespace URIs (`http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd` and `http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco`) match what you have in your xml exactly. The URIs in your comment were automatically formatted so the "http://" part wasn't shown.

Also, [see here](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes) for more information on using XPath in lxml with namespaces.

Comment: Daniel, i get the following error - IndexError: list index out of range , if I remove the index, the elem object is blank.

Comment: @MapMan - then the xpath isn’t matching. I’m guessing that you didn’t show your complete xml and there is a default namespace. Do you have something like `xmlns=“some uri”` in your actual xml?

Comment: Yes, the xml is too large to show, hence i only showed the tags that were relevant.

Comment: @MapMan - Do you have an xmlns in your XML? If so, let me know what it is and I will update my answer.

Comment: there are 2, xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"  and xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco"

Comment: @MapMan - Both of those have prefixes (`gmd` and `gco`). Do you have any without a prefix? (Like `xmlns="..."`.)

Comment: @MapMan - I think I know what's happening...are your elements really like `gmd:CI_Date` instead of `_gmd_CI_Date`?

Comment: yes, originally they are like that gmd:CI_Date as I was having trouble with accessing the tags, i renamed them to gmd_CI_Date and then was able to work with it, and at the end rename them back to gmd:CI_Date

Comment: @MapMan - Ok that makes a huge difference. Glad we got that figured out. I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: @MapMan - I've updated my answer. Please let me know if you still have issues.

Answer (score 1):

The "issue" that you have is not that there are multiple `_gco_Date` elements, but that your task is not to find one element and do something to that same element. Although you haven't stated this explicitly (and it isn't clear what possible structure variations the document might have), I could formulate your goal as follows:

> find and modify an element with tag `_gco_Date` that has a parent
>   (tagged _gmd_date?) which in turn has a sibling with a child having
>   `_gmd_CI_DateTypeCode` tag if and only if that latter tag has an
>   attribute 'codeListValue' equal to 'revision'.

If this (or something similar) is what you need, then you have to use the document structure rather than simply iterate over the elements without regard to what's where. The element-tree object gives you everything you need to achieve this (you can get the parent, list of children, list of siblings, etc.).

This is a primitive example that you can use as a base (NOT the best coding in the world, just a prototype!):

```
import lxml.etree
p=lxml.etree.ETCompatXMLParser()
p.feed(open("test.xml").read())
d=p.close()

def dt_rev(e):
   """this finds if 'e' has a child node with the right tag and attribute value codeListValue == revision """
   for c in e.iterchildren():
     if c.tag == "_gmd_CI_DateTypeCode" and c.attrib['codeListValue'] == 'revision':
       return True
   return False

for e in d.getiterator():
    if e.tag == "_gco_Date":
        p = e.getparent()
        for s in p.itersiblings():
            if dt_rev(s):
                print ("found it!", e.text)
                # add code here to modify the element "e" as needed
```